# Thread-safe sequential number generator in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion

If I have a Generator.cfc with methods:

```
numeric function next()
{
    return variables.num++;   // Is ++ an atomic operation??
}
```

And:

```
application.generator = new generator();
```

If every request calls application.generator.next(), will this generator ever generate the same number twice on heavy load?  In another word... is this thread-safe?  If not, where should the lock be?

Comment: Related blog post: Thread-safety of integer counters in ColdFusion - http://blog.bullamakanka.net/2010/01/thread-safety-of-integer-counters-in.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it atomic by wrapping the increment in a lock.  Since `++` requires three operations (fetch, add, store) I don't think it's atomic on its own on any platform.

Comment: I think you're right about `++` but there are atomic ways of incrementing without locks on some platforms. `Interlocked.Increment` on .NET, for example. If Java has an equivalent, it might be possible to call that directly and avoid the performance hit of locking.

Comment: I see I didn't read far enough before commenting, Java does have such a construct, as Bob points out.

Answer (score 5):

You could also look into the Java 5 class [Atomic Integer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

The ColdFusion code you need is something like this (I haven't tested it):

```
<cfset i = createObject("java", "java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger").init(startValue) />
<cfset newValue = i.incrementAndGet() />
```

Answer (score 3):

Yep, as Donnie pointed out CFLOCK is your friend here.